# How to display node names in Preview -view?

Tags: gephi, graph-visualization

```
Gephi v0.9.1 64bit
Windows 7 64bit
```

I can import CSV files and I get the expected graph in `Overview` view，but in the `Preview` view the node names don't show. I don't know how to resolve it.

The configuration of my graph is like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can change the order of rendering by selecting the "manage renderers" tab, shown in this screenshot.

[image]

Move "default node label" to the top and see if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to refresh.
Refresh button is here[image] .

Or maybe you gephi is crashed. You can reboot it.